# Host on VPN, Guest VM on NAT Limitations?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, nmap

My host computer is using an Azure PPP VPN to connect to my company's network.  My guest VM (Kali Linux) can only run Nmap scans on devices connected to my company's network if the Virtual Box Network option I select is either NAT or NAT Network.  Bridged mode won't work.

I have two questions:

1. What's the difference between NAT and NAT Network, specifically in regards to running nmap & vuln scanners?
2. Alot of the pentesting tutorials that I have read say to get the best results, you want your guest Kali VM to be on bridged mode.  What limitations am I facing by being on NAT mode as far as vulnerability assessments are concerned (i.e. running nmap, tenable, qualys, openVAS vuln scanners)?

Also, is there a good course or book I can read to understand these topics better? Would studying for and passing the COMPTIA Network+ certification give me a good grasp what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bridged mode will never work with PPP connections, as a bridge can only forward packets between networks using the same MAC layer, and PPP connections don't actually have a MAC layer at all.

> What's the difference between NAT and NAT Network, specifically in regards to running nmap & vuln scanners?

In VirtualBox, the main difference is that "NAT" puts each VM in an isolated network with a predefined IP configuration, while "NAT Network" allows multiple VMs to be within the same network and you can choose your own IP configuration. Both are equally isolated from the outside, however.

> Alot of the pentesting tutorials that I have read say to get the best results, you want your guest Kali VM to be on bridged mode. What limitations am I facing by being on NAT mode as far as vulnerability assessments are concerned (i.e. running nmap, tenable, qualys, openVAS vuln scanners)?

Bridge mode may be important for tools that scan the *local subnet*, e.g. ARP-scans (or even ARP-spoofing exploit tools). But when you're talking to "remote" hosts (i.e. outside of your subnet), you wouldn't be able to do any that anyway, so having the VM be in a routed or NATed network shouldn't matter much.

VirtualBox's NAT is done in userspace, though (i.e. it's not merely the kernel forwarding existing packets, it's the VBox.exe process creating *new* packets and TCP connections on behalf of a VM doing the same) and this may affect what "nonstandard" operations the guest OS can do.

For example, in addition to simply making TCP connections (full handshake), Nmap also has various scan modes that involve sending *just* the SYN and not following it up, or sending packets with outright weird TCP flags. Kernel-level routing (and/or NAT) wouldn't have much of a problem with this, but VirtualBox's userspace NAT might be completely unable to reproduce such unusual packets.